# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" when saving a PictureBox Image

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have developed a WinForms application which works correctly under Windows 8.1, but when I try to run it on Windows 7 (32 bit), it throws an error:

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

The error originates from the call to `Save` below:

```
PictureBox p1 = (PictureBox)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
p1.Image.Save(
    @path
        + @"\" 
        + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-hh.mm.ss")
        + i
        + ".jpeg", 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Any thoughts on the cause of the error?

Comment: and path is C:\car rental\

Comment: `/` would be treated as a \ so would attempt to write to`C:\car rental\dd\MM\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is raising due to writing images on a C Drive. It is a permission issue in fact.

Please note :

1. YOU cannot write directly on C Drive.
2. YOU have to make a folder and uncheck read only check.

Apply and save. 
let me know, if there is still issue.

Comment: try to use another Drive D or E for a while and check your code.

Comment: let me know if it help you

Comment: Mark my answer  useful, so other could get a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the forward slashes in the filename are the problem.  I replaced them with periods and was able to save the file.  (Note that in any case you will need the appropriate permissions on the "C:\car rental\" directory.)

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the forward slash is a reserved character that is not allowed in filenames.  Excerpt:

```
The following reserved characters:

< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Comment: thanks sir I remove / and - from file name and its works